# Random point inside boundary

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, random

Given an ASCII art with simple closed paths using  `|` and `-` (pipes and dashes), output a random point inside the boundary.

Eg. given:

```
----              ----
|  |-   ---  =>   |12|-   ---
|   |   | |       |345|   |6|
-----   ---       -----   ---
Any point 1-6 should have an equal probability of being printed.
```

### Specs

- Take a string, list of strings or a matrix containing `|`, `-`,
- Output either the ASCII art with a space replaced by a constant character other than a pipe, dash or space or print the two-dimensional/one-dimensional index.
- All adjacent pipe-dash pairs are connected
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins

### Test cases

```
---
|1|
---

----
|12|-   ---
|345|   |6|
-----   ---

 ---
 |1|
--2--
|345|
-----

-------
|1---2|
|3|4|5|
|6---7|
-------

--- ---
|1| |2|
|3---4|
|56789|
---A---
  |B|
---C---
|DEFGH|
|I---J|
|K| |L|
--- ---


    ---
    |1|
    ---
---     ---
|2|     |3|         (4 simple closed paths)
---     ---
    ---
    |4|
    ---
```

Comment: What does it mean "output a point"? Output its coordinates?

Comment: What is the definition of connected?  Eg, it looks as if the pipe characters could all be asterisks, and connected just means adjacent?

Comment: @Jonah More of a plus than an asterisk, but yes, updated, thanks.

Comment: [Suggested test case.](https://tio.run/##K8go@P9fV1dXAYi5agxrFGqMarhqjIE8EyBtamZuYVnDBeQ5guQVFGqcwDxnsGoXVzd3D6AqTyDPC0h7A3X7gOVBpv3/DwA) (it has a space at all four sides, none of which are considered inside a boundary).

Comment: What is expected output for [this testcase](https://tio.run/##K8go@P9fAQh0dXW5QHSNQg0XjA/ECjA2UFwBJo8sjkPv//8A)?

Comment: @tsh ty, added.

Comment: There's a 'zero width space' character (U+200B) right before the 2nd test case.

Comment: @Arnauld thanks, I have no idea how two invisible characters snuck into my test cases.

Answer (score 5):

## MATL, <s>19</s> <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
36yy>t0ZI-flZr(
```

*2 bytes saved thanks to @LuisMendo*

Input is provided as a 2D character array and the random point is replaced by `$`

Try it out at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=36yy%3Et0ZI-flZr%28&inputs=%5B%27---+---%27%3B%27%7C+%7C+%7C+%7C%27%3B%27%7C+---+%7C%27%3B%27%7C+++++%7C%27%3B%27---+---%27%3B%27++%7C+%7C++%27%3B%27---+---%27%3B%27%7C+++++%7C%27%3B%27%7C+---+%7C%27%3B%27%7C+%7C+%7C+%7C%27%3B%27---+---%27%5D&version=22.7.4)

**Explanation**

```
      % Implicitly retrieve the 2D character array input
36    % Push the literal 36 (ASCII for $) to the stack
y     % Make a copy of the character array
y     % Copy the value 36
>     % Create a boolean 2D array where all values with ASCII > '$' (36) are TRUE
      % these are the elements == '|' or '-' that make up the boundary
t     % Duplicate this boolean 2D array
0ZI   % Perform the morphological fill operation to set the value of all elements
      % within the boundaries to TRUE also
-     % Subtract the boundary to leave TRUE values only for elements that are 
      % inside the boundary
f     % Find the index values of all remaining TRUE values
lZr   % Pick one at random
(     % And assign the '$' (36) to that element in the original input
      % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>82</s> <s>81</s> 77 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υι≔⌈ＥυＬιθＰ⭆⪫υ¶⎇⁼ι ψι↖Ｂ⁺²θ⁺²Ｌυψ¤_↘ＴθＬυＦＬυＦθ«Ｊκι¤ »ＵＭＫＡ⎇⁼ι_ψι≔ΦＫＡ⁼ι θ§≔θ‽Ｌθ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDJagMxDD3HX2GmFxkylx6bU7pBQgIhTW@FMDTOjImXGY@dhabfPpXqbIXKGFvS03uSPqvCf7pCd92uUlpyGNk6hrfglS1BCD6LbQWxz5UYsGHbqtLCtNgrEw2@NWUm0pahAiWE6PMGYdOog6qRIEDiIeDYKUvo7MNmiFtIbwt/gJcmFroFhQlO8QMpCSJxWwkP7/VErgO6j24PMx1buCeNPj//T@KRtA@Ie1VaQ7bMLgzPbmfnqqyIZOGVgea2aMDWznO4Bviv3wj@xXrjaOqFg00avpeoOVF/MxzpyRlT2BXMpNwMMfX/VMvrVJcFIlOQ/rbw7xpOe0zoYRjZldxT33OUc@bcbUO47A776Tqe5zldxo/psOTjZUeejGInY12@1T8) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated strings and marks the random selection with a `#`. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι≔⌈ＥυＬιθ
```

Input the strings and calculate the width of the ASCII art.

```
Ｐ⭆⪫υ¶⎇⁼ι ψι
```

Output the art but with spaces replaced with background.

```
↖Ｂ⁺²θ⁺²Ｌυψ¤_↘ＴθＬυ
```

Add extra background padding, fill it with `_`s, and then remove the extra padding.

```
ＦＬυＦθ«Ｊκι¤ »
```

Replace any remaining background with spaces.

```
ＵＭＫＡ⎇⁼ι_ψι
```

Replace any remaining padding with background.

```
≔ΦＫＡ⁼ι θ§≔θ‽Ｌθ#
```

Randomly replace a space with a `#`.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>81</s> <s>78</s> 77 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.B€SðQ2Fø1δ.ø}©˜ƶ®gäΔ2Fø0δ.ø}2Fø€ü3}®*εεÅsyøÅsM]¤θ©δÜ€¦˜0K®Êðs.;ÐÏSāDΩQ·.;0ð:
```

Uses `2` as random character.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fz@lR05rgwxsCjdwO7zA8t0Xv8I7aQytPzzm27dC69MNLzk0BiRtAxEFMoOrDe4xrD63TOrf13NbDrcWVh3cASd/YQ0vO7Ti08tyWw3OASg4tOz3HwPvQusNdhzcU61kfnnC4P/hIo8u5lYGHtutZGxzeYPX/v5KSkq6urgIQc9UogCGQBomAaBCo4YLJK4BlEaohsgjVNcjyQHP/6@rm5evmJFZVAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaCkU6nDpRSUmJeSn6uQX1oCE3RR@q/n9KhpTfDhDYFGbod3GJ7bond4R@2hlafnHNt2aF364SXnpoDEDSDiICZQ9eE9xrWH1mmd23pu6@HW4srDO4Ckb@yhJed2HFp5bsvhOUAlh5adnmPgfWjd4a7DG4r1rA9PONwffKTR5dzKwEPb9awNDm@w@q@kF6ZzaJv9/2glXV3dmLwahZqYPCBLSUdB6VFDty5UUKFGV0FBAcZRgGCISl2oDEgHRAVMSgGuHKoQpEQXAkASIK01YCshOuAiUDVw5XBTahQwHKkLtkcXmzEgTTDLoS6DuxrhFwU0PTUoasC@gnldAeZtuAjE9woIFygghYwCikasJijF/tfVzcvXzUmsqgQA).

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Pad the input with trailing spaces to make it a rectangle, and add an additional border of spaces. Then convert it to a matrix of 0s for `|` and `-`, and give each space an unique 1-based integer value.

```python
.B           # Blockify the (implicit) multi-line input by adding trailing spaces,
             # and then split it on newlines
  €S         # Convert each line to a list of characters
    ðQ       # Check for each character whether it's a space (1 if space; 0 otherwise)
2Fø1δ.ø}     # Add a border of 1s:
2F     }     #  Loop 2 times:
  ø          #   Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
    δ        #   Map over each inner list/row:
   1 .ø      #    Surround it with a leading/trailing 1
©            # After the loop: store the matrix in variable `®` (without popping)
 ˜           # Flatten it to a single list
  ƶ          # Multiply each value by its 1-based index
   ®g        # Push the length (aka amount of rows) of matrix `®`
     ä       # Split the list of integers back into a matrix of that many rows
```

[Try just this first step online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fz@lR05rgwxsCjdwO7zA8t0Xv8I7aQytPzzm27dC69MNL/v9XUlJ61NCtCwRcNQoKNboKCgpQtgIE13CBJKHiQNX/dXXz8nVzEqsqAQ)

Step 2: Flood-fill the positive values in the matrix to identify the islands of spaces:

```python
Δ            # Loop until it no longer changes to flood-fill:
 2Fø0δ.ø}    #  Add a border of 0s around the matrix:
 2F     }    #   Loop 2 times:
   ø         #    Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
     δ       #    Map over each row:
    0 .ø     #     Add a leading/trailing 0
 2Fø€ü3}     #  Convert it into overlapping 3x3 blocks: 
 2F    }     #   Loop 2 times again:
   ø         #    Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
    €        #    Map over each inner list:
     ü3      #     Convert it to a list of overlapping triplets
 ®*          #  Multiply each 3x3 block by the value in matrix `®`
             #  (so the 0s remain 0s)
 εεÅsyøÅsM   #  Get the largest value from the horizontal/vertical cross of each 3x3
             #  block:
 εε          #   Nested map over each 3x3 block:
   Ås        #    Pop and push its middle row
     y       #    Push the 3x3 block again
      ø      #    Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
       Ås    #    Pop and push its middle rows as well (the middle column)
         M   #    Push the flattened maximum of the entire (scoped) stack,
             #    which is the flattened maximum of the cross of the current 3x3 block
]            # Close the nested maps and flood-fill loop
```

[Try just the first two steps online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fz@lR05rgwxsCjdwO7zA8t0Xv8I7aQytPzzm27dC69MNLzk0BiRtAxEFMoOrDe4xrD63TOrf13NbDrcWVh3cASd/Y//@VlJQeNXTrAgFXjYJCja6CggKUrQDBNVwgSag4UPV/Xd28fN2cxKpKAA)

Step 3: Remove the border and all right-padded trailing space-integers. Then replace that same value to 0s and every other value to 1s in the input-string.

```python
¤            # Push the last row (without popping the matrix)
 θ           # Pop and push its last item
  ©          # Store this space-integer in variable `®` (without popping)
   δ         # Map over each row with this space-integer as argument:
    Ü        #  Remove all trailing space-integers from the row
     €       # Map over each row again:
      ¦      #  Remove its first character (the leading column of space-integers)
       ˜     # Then flatten the matrix to a list
        0K   # Remove all 0s (the "-" and "|")
          ®Ê # Check for each remaining spaces-value that it's NOT equal to `®`
             # (1 if it's a space inside a boundary; 0 if it's a space outside boundary)
ð            # Push a space character " "
 s           # Swap so this list of 0s/1s is at the top
  .;         # Replace all spaces in the (implicit) input one by one with these 0s/1s
```

[Try just the first three steps online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fz@lR05rgwxsCjdwO7zA8t0Xv8I7aQytPzzm27dC69MNLzk0BiRtAxEFMoOrDe4xrD63TOrf13NbDrcWVh3cASd/YQ0vO7Ti08tyWw3OASg4tOz3HwPvQusNdhzcU61n//6@kpPSooVsXCLhqFBRqdBUUFKBsBQiu4QJJQsWBqv/r6ubl6@YkVlUCAA)

Step 4: Transform all `1`s into `0`s, except for a random one, which we'll make `2` instead.

```python
Ð            # Triplicate the modified input-string
 Ï           # Pop two copies, and only keep all 1s
  S          # Convert this string of 1s to a list of 1s
   ā         # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping the list of 1s)
    D        # Duplicate it
     Ω       # Pop and push a random integer from this list
      Q      # Check which one in the list is equal to it
             # (so we have a list of 0s with one random 1)
       ·     # Double each, so the 1 becomes a 2 (0s remains 0)
        .;   # Then replace all 1s in the modified input one by one with these 0s/2s
```

[Try just the first four steps online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fz@lR05rgwxsCjdwO7zA8t0Xv8I7aQytPzzm27dC69MNLzk0BiRtAxEFMoOrDe4xrD63TOrf13NbDrcWVh3cASd/YQ0vO7Ti08tyWw3OASg4tOz3HwPvQusNdhzcU61kfnnC4P/hIo8u5lYGHtutZ//@vpKT0qKFbFwi4ahQUanQVFBSgbAUIruECSULFgar/6@rm5evmJFZVAgA)

Step 5: Finally replace all `0`s back to spaces. After which we output the result.

```python
0ð:          # Replace every 0 back to a space
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 32 bytes

```
2(ðvø.∩)∩ðÞIk□"λhn÷:k□ẊṠJ↔";Ẋ÷F℅
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLilqHGm2Y7d8KoUyIsIjIow7B2w7gu4oipKeKIqcOww55Ja+KWoVwizrtobsO3OmvilqHhuorhuaBK4oaUXCI74bqKw7dG4oSFIiwiIiwiIC0tLSBcbiB8IHwgXG4tLSAtLVxufCAgIHxcbi0tLS0tIl0=)

Expects a rectangular matrix containing `|`, `-`,  . Returns a 2D index.

### How?

Surround the input with spaces from all sides.

```
2(     )  # repeat twice:
  ð       #   push a space
   vø.    #   vectorized surround
      ∩   #   transpose
        ∩ # transpose
```

Find the coordinates of all spaces that are in the outside component.

```
ðÞI                  # get the coordinates of all spaces
   k□                # push cardinal directions [[0,1],[1,0],[0,-1],[-1,0]]
     "               # pair
      λ           ;Ẋ # apply the following function until a fixed point:
                         Takes a pair [coordinates of all spaces,  coordinates spaces reached so far]  
       h             #   head
        n            #   argument
         ÷           #   push each to stack
          :          #   duplicate
           k□        #   push cardinal directions [[0,1],[1,0],[0,-1],[-1,0]]
             Ẋ       #   cartesian product
              Ṡ      #   vectorising sum
               J     #   join the top two item on the stack
                ↔    #   keep only those items of a that are in b
                 "   #   pair
```

Now we have the pair `[coordinates of all spaces,  coordinates of spaces reachable from one of the sides]`.

```
÷   # push each to stack
 F  # remove items from a that are in b
  ℅ # choose a random item
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),<s>181 180</s> 178 bytes

```javascript
f=x=>[...x+0,n=0].map(_=>{for(i in x)for(j in e=x[i])for(k of'0123')(x[+i+--k%2]||++n)[+j+--k%2]?r=n=>Math.random()*n|0:1/e[j]?e[j]=0:0})&&x[p=r(x.length)][q=r(n)]<'!'?[p,q]:f(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZBBToQwGIX3nKIuHFqBTmHUBVo4gSfoNEKgMGU6LQPENLEm7r2lF0Egzr94@b73715XfpRjNch@irSpxTw31NKMYYxtQEJNCceXsofvNPtszAAlkBpYtGK3oqCWSb75GZjGJ3Fy8BG0LJBBFJ3vE@5cEGjEgu7f84Fqmr2V0wkPpa7NBaIH7Uga7wXreL4GJSn5QrudZT0doMVK6HY6Ic6ui2rEX/07P2d9eOVpAy2aX7zK6NEogZVpYQML7/f7J1rOc3HiIgDAxofHJ7ewe3be@rz1BR5Er8pKwP2x3rehD3yERyWXIg6jeOFeyak46mJb4rYORwjNfw)

Didn't expect it runs in time

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 114 bytes

```
^
_¶
$
¶_
P`.+
.+
_$&_
+`_ | _|(?<=(.)*)( |_)(.*¶(?<-1>.)*(?(1)$)(?!\2))[ _]
_$3_
@` 
#
^_+¶_|_+¶_+$|_+(¶)_
$1
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY0xDsIwDEX3fwojImQ3SqXACoQjsAN1GRhYGCrGnCsHyMWC2/Ltb8tPsj29vu/PM7Y2QGuBQy2K69h7WKrbKfyolEkzp@OJe@mEKatw39ViKMSzMU4cxQmnzX0vciN92O5BcRkJWwzq7WpeqnfWuRZRuAgFtUYhhNmwN0tgnc3ItGpmf/0A) Marks the random selection with a `#`. Explanation:

```
^
_¶
$
¶_
P`.+
.+
_$&_
```

Pad the input and surround it with `_`s on all sides.

```
+`_ | _|(?<=(.)*)( |_)(.*¶(?<-1>.)*(?(1)$)(?!\2))[ _]
_$3_
```

Flood fill the `_`s so that only interior spaces remain.

```
@` 
#
```

Randomly replace one with the output marker.

```
^_+¶_|_+¶_+$|_+(¶)_
$1
_
```

Remove the padding and replace any remaining `_`s with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 770 bytes:

```py
import random as U
E=enumerate
def T(b,x,y):
 D={}
 for i in b:D[i[x]]=D.get(i[x],[])+[i[y]]
 return D
def B(b):
 P=[(x,y)for x,r in E(b)for y,k in E(r)if' '!=k];p=[*P]
 while p:
  q=[(r:=p.pop(0),[r])]
  while q:
   F=0
   (x,y),r=q.pop(0)
   for X,Y in[(1,0),(-1,0),(0,-1),(0,1)]:
    j,k=x+X,y+Y
    V=(j,k)
    if 0<=j<len(b)and 0<=k<len(b[0])and(len(r)<2 or V!=r[-2]):
     if(j==x and'-'==b[j][k])or(k==y and'|'==b[j][k])or b[x][y]!=b[j][k]:
      if V in r:yield r;p=[*({*p}-{*r})];F=1;break
      elif V in P:q+=[(V,[*r,V])]
   if F:break
def f(b):
 K=[]
 for i in B(b):
  Q,W=T(i,0,1),T(i,1,0)
  K+=[(x,y)for x,r in E(b)for y,k in E(r)if' '==k and x in Q and min(Q[x])<=y<=max(Q[x])and y in W and min(W[y])<=x<=max(W[y])]
 x,y=U.choice(K)
 b[x][y]='*'
 return b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLRT9swEMafl7/i4CV261RteZlK72UqvCBNIEEBedbUQDrctEnqBi0R5W/v7pwENolJ20PlfOfffba/a1GXT3l28rlwh4PdFLkrwS2yx3wDix3cBGeYZM@bxC3KJHhMlnAtYlWpWk4CmOHLawDL3IEFm0E8mWmrK2NwNviRlIK/lTayT9XamABcUj67DGbe54uI2eMStWA7dqmUY58z2mFZq7SRTtplCOERpua0QN27JK@fT3adQEEOsCULN8FiUOSFGEqlnZFEtMiWETjHIS/@KOVw27Jc46Pu1D0dpcVIUb@ImmWoopFfRtJ4E1ipFKv@nar7917PUVDJu4BdwnCKq@k6yej@FCDLtJF6aLgiWDg5HQMdOT9Cp6OxkY019YsVYgXEhVGIGOuV0amRuRMpYu3r@z/qEFPAlOxRV2ud@CpzTs5NapusH8H51MRLr3iNXnruVZrTcxydxi5ZpG1Lsu6aLifbPgU6V7rn1LxJkh3PJw3Ps1s2s7tAbX6bfztRuFK3eC2s4uAUf3CcVL/o//usEVN@MVRcvfKfG5uJK3qxnGI9xc2iahRv1UzdvlG3FApRVUN5Rfekk/Fm8PCU24dEXNCF2vgw7IVv/834sMPj4@MgiqJgD3u/st6NunLUBAa0DXsWDUrC/3xL1NV969i3soaACSAEuqYGb8CTtzMaT@7Y8zW8b6e7fWb9NMr8@8KVoqTwP7XP0LpnzftklnZdJk58zbNEQTnYFWtbivBbFkoKJgjeOdF67SSbFc5mxIWDVU6pWik/REf/wY7/xn4En3wMH34B)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES11), 168 bytes

Expects a matrix of characters and returns the coordinates `[x,y]` of a cell.

```javascript
m=>(o=[])[m.map((r,y)=>r.map((C,x)=>(g=(x,y,r=m[y],c=r?.[x])=>1/c?[-1,0,1,2].every(d=>g(x+d%2,y+~-d%2),r[x]=g)|(r[x]=c):!!c/C)(x,y)?n=o.push([x,y]):0))|Math.random()*n]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZC_btswEMbRVU9xCVCIF1OMnalIQHsIWnTplFHWIEiUrEIiXUouLJTti3QJigbo63Rsnyb8YynwFgEi77778fgdf_6WqhSPvyr-dBiq5N2_Px1fE8XTDNOOdfmeEE1H5Gsdknt6tAmpOTnSkWrepWNGC643LD1mtrK6LjZpsqJLuqI3GRNfhR5Jydc1OS7Ktzd0XPxI7I5UW57XaIgPCry9uCiu79G1xY3kiu0P_Y6kNs3wdoloPuXDjulclqojeCWzk9-_Wnw5NFqQuOpjZFrk5YemFQ-jLMgS2aAeBt3ImiDr920zkMut3MpLZJXS7_NiR3rga_gWAbRigA449C-gxdzQHkkZY32GdyfSGoMxs3hFOi-6h7CTWCW-ip1QKNmrVrBW1SS8pHZ9NPusGkniGPEUbWWMsAC_30XfMQz2-P_NxyRJIgMmcrtbEgifFcG4JAA28b8Hk0mP3AqR08EWYEIDFPqF844z7iLfY8qnugtOF50Dxnsxc322MNuCM9qc1SMIPv08EPzP8aRPI0_Xw8ucs_6KPuFFnwE)
(with some post-processing to insert an asterisk at the chosen position)

#### How?

For each space in the input matrix, we process a recursive flood-fill to test whether we can 'escape' through a boundary. We keep track of each starting point for which this is not the case and return one of them.

#### Commented

```javascript
m =>                      // m[] = input matrix
(o = [])[                 // start with o[] set to an empty array
  m.map((r, y) =>         // for each row r[] at index y in m[]:
    r.map((C, x) =>       //   for each character C at index x in r[]:
      ( g = (             //     g is a recursive function taking:
          x, y,           //       (x, y) = current position
          r = m[y],       //       r[] = current row
          c = r?.[x]      //       c = character at this position
        ) =>              //
        1 / c ?           //     if c is a space:
          [-1, 0, 1, 2]   //       array of directions
          .every(d =>     //       for each direction d:
            g(            //         do a recursive call:
              x + d % 2,  //           add dx to x
              y + ~-d % 2 //           add dy to y
            ),            //         end of recursive call
            r[x] = g      //         start by invalidating the current cell
          ) |             //       end of every()
          (r[x] = c)      //       restore the current cell
        :                 //     else:
          !!c / C         //       return a truthy value (1/0 = +∞) if and
                          //       only if c is defined and C is a space 
      )(x, y) ?           //     initial call to g; if truthy:
        n =               //       update n to the length of o[] ...
          o.push([x, y])  //       ... once [x, y] has been added to o[]
      :                   //     else:
        0                 //       do nothing
    )                     //   end of inner map()
  )                       // end of outer map()
  | Math.random() * n     // pick a random item from o[]
]                         //
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 238 bytes

```python
e=enumerate
a,*r={i+1j*j:c<'!'for i,r in e(open(0))for j,c in e(r)},
while q:=[i for i in a if a[i]][:1]:
 g,*v=1,
 while q:
  c,*q=q;a[c]=0;v+=[c]
  for i in-1,1,-1j,1j:q+=[c+i]*a.get(c+i,0);g&=c+i in a
 r+=v*g
print({*map(str,r)}.pop())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BbsMgEEX3nGK6SQAPkVE3kV1OYrFAFnGwGoyp46qKe3YXHFkpo9F8/fdhCD/TdfDv5xDX1Srr7zcbzWSJQR7VwxWy533VfhzfjpchgsPUHiwdgvW0ZCybPbZPM7JfJN9X92lhrFTjYLuSmQF3AdM4rZtK6opAh3xWEgnscQLQIh/VWJum1aqs50Ilkez9ESFRopA9yr4aMyyc5ubU2YkmiSWru4NKattHIBZq5h0J0fmJPvjNBPo1RUx/PIUhUMbWVQgBqckCW6WZnTzzWcjOYaOv9JO@0st//gc)

Flood-fills from every space position and stores the ones that do not go out of bounds. Then it relies on hash randomization for strings to pop a random coordinate from the final set.

Comment: that's a lot of golfing :P